# C ++ pointers cannot change their original values

Tags: c++

The following code snippet:

```cpp
bool pinger::unpack(icmp *packet, int iphdrlen, int recv_len, char *buf)
{
    if ((recv_len - iphdrlen) < 8)
    {
        return false;
    }
    packet = (struct icmp *)(buf + iphdrlen);
    std::cout << (int)packet->icmp_type << std::endl;
    return true;
}

int pinger::echo()
{

    int packet_id = generate_indetity();
    int recv_len = 0;
    timeval send_timeval, recv_timeval;
    socklen_t *addr_len = (socklen_t *)malloc(sizeof(sockaddr *));
    char buffer[PACKET_BUFFER_SIZE];

    icmp *icmp_packet = (icmp *)buffer;
    int packsize = pack(icmp_packet, ICMP_ECHO, 0, 0, packet_id, data_len);
    sendto(sock_fd, buffer, packsize, 0, (sockaddr *)&dest_sockaddr, sizeof(sockaddr)
    memset(buffer, 0, PACKET_BUFFER_SIZE);
    recv_len = recvfrom(sock_fd, buffer, PACKET_BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (sockaddr *)&dest_sockaddr, addr_len);
    ip *ip_packet = (struct ip *)buffer;
    int iphdrlen = ip_packet->ip_hl << 2;
    std::cout << (int)icmp_packet->icmp_type << std::endl;
    if (unpack(icmp_packet, iphdrlen, recv_len, buffer))
    {
        std::cout << (int)icmp_packet->icmp_type << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Its output is:

```sh
$ 69
$ 0
$ 69
```

Why can't the value of `icmp_packet` be modified by passing the icmp struct through a pointer?

> After modification, the value of `icmp_packet` can be modified through C ++ reference passing, but why isn't pointer passing possible?

Comment: Because if you're not passing a reference, you're passing a copy. The `packet` in `pinger::unpack` is a copy of the one in `pinger::echo`, and if you modify that copy in `unpack`, then the original pointer remains unchanged.

Comment: Because you are not passing a pointer to `icmp_packet`. You are passing a pointer to `buffer`. You can change the thing the points to by using the pointer, not the pointer itself. If you want to change a pointer that way, you need a pointer to the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that by default all arguments are passed *by value*, which means the value you use when calling the function is *copied* into the local argument variable in the function.

Modifying such a copy (for example by assigning to it) modifies only the local variable (the copy), not variable you used in the call.

To solve that you need to pass such arguments *by reference*:

```
// Pass this argument by reference
//                        v
bool pinger::unpack(icmp *& packet, int iphdrlen, int recv_len, char *buf)
```

---

I would also recommend that you pass `buf` as a pointer to constant bytes (`char const*` or the more common `const char *`), to enforce the contract that the function will not modify the data.

Answer (score 2):

In order to.modify something in a function, you pass a pointer or a reference to the thing being modified. If the thing being modified is a pointer, you need to pass a *pointer (or a reference) to a pointer*.

Comment: C++ has pass-by-reference as a native feature , you should not use the C hack of simulating pass-by-reference by passing by pointer

Comment: @M.M OP appears to know that. I have mentioned that as well.

Comment: @M.M Is there any actual reason, or is this just dogma?

Comment: @M.M I have to say, I, not the OP, don't feel very comfortable with references coming from C, but I guess I'll get used to it :)